# start day of the year in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have to set starting day of the year (01-01-2014 / 01-01-2015...)HOw to set in Jquery UI datepicker. I am using the below code

```
 $(function () {
            $(".datepicker1").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy', changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true, defaultDate: new Date(2014, 00, 01)
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
var firstDay = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), 0, 1)
```

from the javascript reference the suitable constructor is

```
Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

all parameters are optional

Answer (score 1):

You can make it like this.

HTML:

```
<input id="firstdayofyear"/>
```

JS:

```
$("#firstdayofyear").kendoDatePicker({});
var todayDate = new Date("2014", "0", "1");
$('#firstdayofyear').data("kendoDatePicker").value(todayDate);
```

See demo -> [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yocwhj8h/2/)

Comment: Thanks buddie.. Your answer is awesome, but i am not using Kendo.. I will use this in my future projects

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var date = new Date(), y = date.getFullYear(), m = date.getMonth();
var firstDay = new Date(y, m, 1);
var lastDay = new Date(y, m + 1, 0);
```

Comment: I tried but didnot work ..
I replaced new Date(2014, 00, 01) with firstday
That didnot work for me